# Magento Cron on shared hosting (hostinger)

Tags: magento, cron, shared-hosting, magento2.1

How can i set up magento cron properly on shared hosting servers, where execution is prohibited via SSH?

i.e Setting up using crontab doesn't work. The temporary solution i have is the following:

```html
*/10 * * * * php public_html/bin/magento cron:run
*/15 * * * * php public_html/bin/magento cache:clean
*/5 * * * * php public_html/bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I have inserted these into the cron job section in cpanel.
This is probably a hideous way of tackling this problem, but atleast indexers are reindexed automatically right now. But when the site goes public, this needs to be set up correctly.

Running Magento 2.1.17

Answer (score 0):

Your cron task for the scheduler is fine, but the other two are a bit weird.

Why do you need to clear your cache & reindex so often ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I guess once a day is fine.

Comment: You should clear your cache after a deployment and reindex after non-handled modifications (like bulk import of data). But you can do those once a day during the night to ease your mind yes :-)